# Passing RoR value into javascript (JQuery) in a view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, progress-bar, actionview

I've been puzzled by the following code. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong that javascript fails to access the value p ? Thanks !

```
<% p=progress_for(contest_score) %> # p is non-zero

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      $('#contest_progressbar').progressbar({value: <%=p%>}); 
      <!--value p becomes 0 when rendered by jquery-->

      $("#contest_progressbar").css({ 'background': 'LightYellow' });
      $("#contest_progressbar > div").css({ 'background': 'Orange' });
      $('#contest_progressbar span.text').text(<%=p%>+'%')
      <!--value p becomes 0 when rendered by jquery-->

   });
</script>
progress: <%=p%> progress bar should be below: # p is the correct value here

<div id='contest_progressbar' style="margin-left:20px; height: 20px;">
  <span class="text"></span>
</div>
```

EDIT: Using straight script tag instead. Same problem though
EDIT2: Seems to be a JQuery problem now. See the html in the comment to Bryan's answer

Comment: That theoretically should work fine from what I see.  When you do "view source" in your browser, is it actually being printed out as processbar({value: 0}) in the HTML output?

Comment: I'm assuming the ruby comments at the end of the javascript lines is something you added for us here, yes?

Comment: Also, is there any particular reason you're using JavaScript to fixed values (which is best like `<span><%= text %></span>`) and style information (which is best in a CSS file)?

Comment: CORRECTION : ghayes, yes view source show {value: 0}. But the value SHOULD NOT be zero. jaydel yes comments are added to this question, not in my code. Just try to explain the difference. @Bryan, the span text code was borrowed from a SO example. Thanks for the suggestion, I'd make that change. Right now, the progressbar is holding things up!

Comment: [CORRECTION : view source actually show the correct non-zero value, my mistake. But when viewed in Firebug, the div for the progress bar has a width value of 0. If I change that to something else in Firebug, the progressbar is displayed. ]

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that jQuery just isn't loading? If you check in your debugger, it might give you a hint, something like `$ is not defined`. If there's a [Prototype/jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) conflict (highly possible if you're using Rails before v3.1), it may fail silently.

It may also be the case that JS code block needs to appear *after* you've loaded jQuery. The reason I'm thinking this is the issue is that, given the information you've provided, something like `$('#contest_progressbar span.text').text(5+'%');` should *always* work if you have jQuery loaded correctly and no other elements with the ID `contest_progressbar`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6JQNe/1/

Also, a few minor points:

- You need `<%= javascript_tag do %>` (note the equals sign) to make sure it renders.
- `"#contest_progressbar > div"` will not match anything

Comment: <div style="margin-left: 20px; width: 256px; height: 20px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% LightYellow;" id="contest_progressbar" class="ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
      <span class="text">32%</span>
    <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left" style="width: 0%; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% Orange;"></div></div>

Comment: Qutie sure JQuery is there. We took care of Prototype/JQuery issue awhile back. (It's Rails 3 we're using btw). See the div generated by Jquery aboove. The problem is that aria-valuenow in the outter div and width in the inner div are both 0. When the progressbar is created by hardcoding a value, that would show up in the mentioned two values.

Comment: Regarding your second minor point, I borrowed the progressbar coloring code here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476573/jquery-ui-how-to-change-the-color-of-a-progressbar)

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. It had nothing too do with JQuery. The div id for the progressbar was clobbered because the code is in a partial, which is called by a view method in a loop. Every calls keep overwriting the same div. The code below produces the result I want.

```
<% pbar_id="pbar_#{contest_score.user_id}" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $$(function(){
      $$('#'+"<%=pbar_id%>").progressbar({'value':<%=p%>})
      $$('#'+"<%=pbar_id%>").css({ 'background':'LightYellow' });
      $$('#'+"<%=pbar_id%>"+' > div').css({ 'background':'Orange' });
   });
 </script>
progress: <%=p%>%
<div id=<%=pbar_id%> style="margin-left:20px; width:256px; height:20px;">
</div>
```