# How to resize the progressbar in JQuery UI

Tags: jquery

I'm having some issues with the JQuery UI progress bar, I can't seem to resize it. I tried adding a height value in my css for the progressbar class but It will only change in width, not height.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Answer (score 3):

Just use [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) like this:

```
$('#progressbar').height(100);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zaHGG/

Comment: Wow, thanks! Also if I might ask, is there an easy way to change the color of the bar?

Comment: That is not that easy, because it uses images for the progress bar, however you can set the background color like this `$("#progressbar").css({ 'background': 'green' });`, also have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1476573/511300