# jQuery UI: How to make a multi colored ProgressBar? Segments colored differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                        value: 35
                });
        });
        </script>
<div id="progressbar">  </div>
```

code taken from : [jQuery UI: How to change the color of a ProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476573/jquery-ui-how-to-change-the-color-of-a-progressbar#_=_)

To make the question clearer : I want the progress bar to have segments and they should be be green from 0% - 59%, yellow from 60% - 89%, and red from 90% - %100%.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI: How to change the color of a ProgressBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476573/jquery-ui-how-to-change-the-color-of-a-progressbar)

Comment: No I don't want the entire progress bar to be the same color. I'm trying to have segements of the progress bar to have different colors.

Comment: have u tried my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with jquery.ui.multiprogressbar.js.

Inorder to set different color to progressbar create set of class as i used in demo and set it to barClass

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E6UPN/60/)

```
    $('#plain').multiprogressbar({
       parts: [
        {value: 59,barClass: "green"},
       {value: 30,barClass: "yellow"},
       {value: 11,barClass: "red"}]
});
```