# Is there any way to breakout the jquery UI progress bar into different sections as well as support > 100%?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I am looking at using the jquery progress bar but i have two requirements that don't seem supported:

1. The ability to put different section into the progress bar.  For example, instead of just having:

Total 100, Current 50 (so 1/2 the progress bar is filled out).  which would look like this:

[image]

I would like to be able to show:

Total 100, Current 50 (which is broken out into 20 from Project A,  30 from Project B and 10 from Project C) where A and B sections can have some different visualization like this:

[image]

2. The ability to show a number > 100%.  I am using this for tracking a fund raising event so its possible that the $$ earned is greater than the goals so would want the progress indicator to keep going outside the boundaries of the progress bar.

Does jquery ui progress bar support these use cases? Is there another javascript plugin or control that is recommended for this use case?

Comment: Not complicated to do this yourself

Comment: Maybe this Javascript component does what you want: http://bug7a.github.io/progressbar.js/.

Comment: How would each section be broken up? If this is showing the amount of collections a day, are we showing the percentage of a total goal? Or the amount of money collected?

Comment: How are the colors selected? Any color relationship to the sections?

Comment: This question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988644/jquery-ui-how-to-make-a-multi-colored-progressbar-segments-colored-differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a basic and **Css Free** override for **jqueryUi** progressbar:

- **multimize** gets progressbar id and an Array of favorite colors, this function breaks the original progress bar to a new version with multi bars according colors array length.
- **multiUpdate** calling this method for update progress bar, this function gives `progressbarId` and an `Array` of bars values.

**a short of what I did:**
just cloning the original bar to many other and using a table to show stats on each Bar. the length of code is because of included styles but you can compress it to at least 30% of this.

### Edit:

added support of Numbers > 100

---

```js
 // this method overrides jqueryUi progress bar
 // the length of <colors> will be number of breakes
 // this method also add a table that presents percentage in position 
function multimize(progressBarId, colors, max) {
 var pbar = $("#"+progressBarId);
 pbar.progressbar({ value: 100 });
 pbar.data('max', max);
 pbar.css("position", "relative");
 $("#"+progressBarId+" div").css({"position": "absolute", "background": colors[colors.length-1],"border":"none"}).attr("id", progressBarId+"_sub"+(colors.length-1));
 var textTable = $('<table></table>').css({"border":"none", "position":"absolute", "color":"white", "width":"100%", "height":"100%"}).attr("id", progressBarId+"_tbl");
 var textRow = textTable.append($('<tr></tr>')).css({"text-align":"center"});
 textRow.append($('<td>d</td>'));
 for (var i=colors.length-2; i>=0; i--) {
  $("#"+progressBarId+" div").clone().appendTo("#"+progressBarId)
   .css({"position": "absolute", "background": colors[i], "border-radius": "0", "width": "1%"})
   .attr("id", progressBarId+"_sub"+i);
   textRow.append($('<td>d</td>')).css({"text-align":"center"});
 }
 pbar.append(textTable);
}
 // this method will be update multimized progressbars
 // this method automatically finalize progressbar
function multiUpdate(progressBarId, values) {
 var pbar = $("#"+progressBarId);
 var i,total = 0;
 var percentes = [];
 for (i=0; i<values.length; i++) total += values[i];
 $("#"+progressBarId+"_tbl").css("width", (total*(100/pbar.data('max')))+"%")
 for (i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
  var perc = values[i]/total*100*(total/100)*(100/pbar.data('max'));
  percentes.push((i==0)?perc:perc+percentes[i-1]);
  $("#"+progressBarId+"_sub"+i).css({"width": percentes[i]+"%"});
  $("#"+progressBarId+"_tbl td:eq("+i+")").text(Math.floor(values[i])).css("width", (values[i]/total)+"%");
 }
 if (total >= pbar.data('max')) {
  finilize(progressBarId);
 }
}

function finilize(progressBarId) {
 // removing demo timer
 clearInterval(timer);
 
 var pbar = $("#"+progressBarId);
 pbar.empty();
 pbar.text("compete "+pbar.data('max')+"%").css({"color":"black", "background":"lightgreen", "text-align":"center"});
}
 
 
// Demo
// here is a demo of progress bar update and finilize
 $(function() {
 multimize("progressbar", ["#06AF8F","#000000","#F94443"], 200);
 });
var classA=0, classB=0, classC=0;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
 classA += (Math.round(Math.random() * (20 - 2) + 2))/30;
 classB += (Math.round(Math.random() * (20 - 1) + 1))/15;
 if (classC<20) classB = Math.min(classB, 15);
 classC += (Math.round(Math.random() * (20 - 7) + 7))/60;
 classC = Math.min(classC, 40);
 multiUpdate("progressbar", [classA,classB,classC]);
}, 100);
```

```html
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="page">
 <div id = "progressbar"></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can accomplish the first part of the question.

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/03yuc3un/

**HTML**

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<div class="form">
  Add Funds:
  <input type="" id="funds" />
  <button id="addBtn">Add</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form {
  padding: 20px;
}

.ui-progressbar-value {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: .25em;
}

.form input {
  width: 4em;
}

#progressbar div.ui-progressbar-value.ui-widget-header:first-of-type {
  z-index: -1;
  display: none;
}

.color-1 {
  background: #FF0000;
}

.color-2 {
  background: #FFA500;
}

.color-3 {
  background: #FFFF00;
}

.color-4 {
  background: #00FF00;
}

.color-5 {
  background: #0000FF;
}

.color-6 {
  background: #FF00FF;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var $pgbr = $("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value: 0,
    max: 100,
    change: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).find(".ui-progressbar-value").eq(0).css("display", "none");
    }
  });
  $("#addBtn").button().click(function(e) {
    var funds = parseInt($("#funds").val());
    var cValue = $pgbr.progressbar("value");
    var sum = cValue + funds;
    if (sum > $pgbr.progressbar("option", "max")) {
      return false;
    }
    $pgbr.progressbar("value", sum);
    if (funds) {
      var $chunk = $("<div>", {
        class: "ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header",
        width: ((funds / $pgbr.progressbar("option", "max")) * 100) + "%"
      });
      var count = $("#progressbar .ui-progressbar-value").length;
      if (count == 0) {
        $chunk.addClass("ui-corner-left");
      }
      if (count <= 6) {
        $chunk.addClass("color-" + count);
      } else {
        $chunk.addClass("color-" + count % 6);
      }
      $chunk.html(funds);
      $pgbr.append($chunk);
    }
  });
});
```

As you can see, there is not a way to make sections naturally with `progressbar()`. This example allows us to add amounts to the progress bar. If the Goal is 100 or 2000, this can be set as `max` during initialization. This example is assuming you are adding money collected in a day toward a goal. Example tests: $30 on day 1, $10 on day 2, $20 on day 3.

When funds are added, it adds another `div` with a width set to a percentage. This will help represent the value properly against the goal. If the goal is $100, the width would be 30%. If the goal is $2000, the width would be 1.5%.

Using CSS, you can assign specific colors. I picked 6 colors and rotate through them based on the number of sections already added. You could do this in a number of different methods.

Now lets say your stretch goal is $5000 and your minimum goal is $2000, this might be a `max` of `2000` initially. If the amount collected exceeds $2000... there's a bit of a logistical issue here. You could iterate each section and resize it to the proper percentage. Personally, I think it might be best to shrink the width of the progress bar itself, and create a 2nd progress bar that can track the surplus.

Feel free to comment with questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure Javascript solution.

It's a function which gets segments as an array of numbers, total as a number, CSS selector of container (string) and optionally an array of colors (as strings).

Segments and total are numbers, not percents. 
The function converts segments to percents and draws the bar.

For your use case, if you have overflow, just add a 4th segment which is the computed overflow (out of the total), with a different color (example 2).

You can style the segment borders with CSS so the overflow is visually distinct

```js
function progress_bar(segments, total, selector, colors) {
  //if no colors default to these 3 colors
  colors = colors || 'green black red'.split(' ');

  //find the container DOM element
  var bar = document.querySelector(selector);
  for (var i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
    child = document.createElement('DIV');

    //compute width in percents relative to total
    var relativeW = total ? segments[i] / total * 100 : 0;
    child.innerHTML = Math.floor(relativeW);
    child.className = 'bar-segment bar-segment--' + (i + 1);
    child.style = 'float:left; height:100%; background: ' + colors[i] + '; width: ' + relativeW + '%;';
    bar.appendChild(child);
  }
}

progress_bar([20, 50, 10], 100, '.progress-demo');

progress_bar([40, 100, 20, 30], 200, '.progress-demo-2', ['green','black','red', 'yellow']);
```

```css
.bar-segment{
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;  
}

.bar-segment--2{
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<h4>1.</h4>

<div class="progress-demo" 
     style="height:20px; width:300px; border: 1px solid gray">
  </div>

<h4>2.</h4>

<div class="progress-demo-2" 
     style="height:20px; width:300px; border: 1px solid gray">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Many people end up using jQuery UI because of the success of the jQuery brand, even when jQuery and jQuery UI are two completely different products. While jQuery is great, jQuery UI tends to have many rough edges. Bootstrap also covers progress bars and is usually simpler to extend and customise. [Check out this example of the Bootstrap progress bar, for example](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaer/tew8h4uw/1/).

If you choose to stick with jQuery UI, you could extend `$.ui.progressbar`, and use it like:

```
pb = $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    values: [30,10,20]
});
```

```js
$.widget("custom.progressbar", $.ui.progressbar, {

    _create: function() {

        // Constrain initial value
        this.oldValue = this.options.value = this._constrainedValue();

        this.element.attr( {
            role: "progressbar",
            "aria-valuemin": this.min
        } );

        this._addClass( "ui-progressbar", "ui-widget ui-widget-content" );
        val_bar = $( "<div><span class='progress-label'></span></div>" ).addClass("ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header");
        
        var bar_sections = this.options.values;
        for (i in bar_sections) {
            var bar_section = val_bar.clone();
            this.element.append(bar_section.addClass('bar_' + i));
        }

        this.valueDivs = this.element.find('.ui-progressbar-value');

        this._refreshValue();
    },

    _refreshValue: function() {
        var values = this.options.values,
            percentage = this._percentage(),
            _total = this.options.values.reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b;}, 0)

        if (_total > 100) {
            this.options.max = _total;
        } else {
            this.options.max = 100;
        }

        for (index = 0; index < values.length; ++index) {
            this.options.value = values[index];
            this.valueDiv = this.valueDivs.eq(index);
            $('.progress-label', this.valueDiv).text(values[index] + '%')
            this._super();
            this.valueDiv
            .width( percentage + "%" );
        }
    },

    _values: function( newValues ) {
        this.options.values = newValues;
        this._refreshValue();
    }
});

initial_values = [30,10,20]

var pb = $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
 values: [30,10,20]
});

function progress(pb) {
  // var val = pb.progressbar("value") || 0;

    initial_values.map(function(x, i, ar){
        if (initial_values[i] < 100) { 
            initial_values[i] = initial_values[i] + 1;
        }
    });

    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        values: initial_values
    });

  setTimeout(progress, 100);
}
progress(pb);
```

```css
 body{
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  margin: 50px;
 }
 .demoHeaders {
  margin-top: 2em;
 }
 #dialog-link {
  padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
 }
 #dialog-link span.ui-icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: .2em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -8px;
 }
 #icons {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #icons li {
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
 }
 #icons span.ui-icon {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px;
 }
 .fakewindowcontain .ui-widget-overlay {
  position: absolute;
 }
 select {
  width: 200px;
 }

    #progressbar {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow:hidden;
     border: 1px solid #dddddd;
     
    }

    html .ui-progressbar-value {
        display: inline-block;
        
    }

    .bar_0 {
        background: #06af8f;
    }
    .bar_1 {
        background: #000;
    }
    .bar_2 {
        background: #fc4242;
    }
    .progress-label {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 30px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .bar_1 .progress-label {
        color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may like multiprogressbar.js

### The CSS

```
#styled{
    margin: 30px;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.green {background: green}
.black {background: black}
.red {background: red}
```

### The HTML

```
<div id="styled"></div>
```

### The JQuery

```
$('#styled').multiprogressbar({
    parts:[{value: 30, text: true, barClass: "green", textClass: "whiteText"},
            {value: 10, text: true, barClass: "black", textClass: "whiteText"},
            {value: 20, text: true, barClass: "red", textClass: "whiteText"}]
});
```

---

**The Result**
[image]

**The Demo [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/ycof0rc4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can implement multi progress bar using simple html and css. Don't need any plugin

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Stacked Progress Bars</h2>
  <p>Create a stacked progress bar by placing multiple bars into the same div with class .progress:</p> 
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-40" role="progressbar">
     40%
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-10" role="progressbar">
     10%
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-20" role="progressbar">
     20%
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.progress {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.progress-bar {
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  -webkit-transition: width .6s ease;
  -o-transition: width .6s ease;
  transition: width .6s ease;
}
.progress-bar-40 {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}
.progress-bar-10 {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.progress-bar-20{
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #d9534f;
 }
 </style>
```

Check this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zLxxmact/2/