# jquery-ui progress bar, color change according to value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been trying to achieve a progress bar wherein, <50 is one color, >50 and <75 is another color and >75 and <85 is yet another color, using jquery-ui progressbar.

I've read quite alot of answers, and I am not able to wrap my head around it.
my js file (I am displaying two progress bars):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    let progressbar = $("#progressbar"), progressLabel = $("#progress-label");
    let progressbar2 = $("#progressbar2"), progressLabel2 = $("#progress-label2");

    progressbar.progressbar({
      value: 0,
      change: function() {
        progressLabel.text(progressbar.progressbar("value") + "% Complete!");
      }
    });

    progressbar2.progressbar({
      value: 0,
      change: function() {
        progressLabel2.text(progressbar2.progressbar("value") + "% Complete!");
      }
    });

    function progress() {
      let val = progressbar.progressbar("value") || 0;
      let val2 = progressbar2.progressbar("value") || 0;

      if (val < 50) {
        progressbar.progressbar("value", val + 1);
      }
      if (val2 < 85) {
        progressbar2.progressbar("value", val2 + 1);
      }
      setTimeout(progress, 20);

    }
    setTimeout(progress, 500);
    // setTimeout(progress2, 500);
  });
});
```

this is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r16bhjwz/) of my work up til now.

Any help is much much much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI: How to change the color of a ProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476573/jquery-ui-how-to-change-the-color-of-a-progressbar)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu the accepted answer to the question isn't working. I might just need a little bit more help here ..

Comment: @nglglhtr fixed up your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/r16bhjwz/4/

Comment: Do you want the color to change for both, example both get green up to 50% and then if the value is more it changes to blue up to 75% and then red after?

Comment: @Twisty I am unable to see a change, could you please re-check and let me know? Also, no, I'd want the effect just for the second one.
Thank you for helping!

Comment: @nglglhtrI made no changes to your code in that fiddle, simply made sure the fiddle worked properly. Adding an answer now with changes.

Comment: @Twisty ohkay. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to change is the `ui-progressbar-value` class element in the progressbar. You can review Theming here: http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/

> **Theming**
>
> The progressbar widget uses the jQuery UI CSS framework to style its look and feel. If progressbar specific styling is needed, the following CSS class names can be used for overrides or as keys for the classes option:
>
> ```
> ui-progressbar: The outer container of the progressbar. This element will additionally have a class of ui-progressbar-indeterminate for indeterminate progressbars. For determinate progressbars, the ui-progressbar-complete class is added once the maximum value is reached.
>     ui-progressbar-value: The element that represents the filled portion of the progressbar.
>         ui-progressbar-overlay: Overlay used to display an animation for indeterminate progressbars.
> ```

So to fix your code, when there is a `change` you can check the value and adjust the `background` of `.ui-progressbar-value` for that object.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/r16bhjwz/26/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <div id="progressbar">
      <div id="progress-label" class="label"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="progressbar2">
      <div id="progress-label2" class="label"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  let progressbar = $("#progressbar"),
    progressLabel = $("#progress-label");
  let progressbar2 = $("#progressbar2"),
    progressLabel2 = $("#progress-label2");

  function checkValue(obj) {
    var val = obj.progressbar("value") || 0;
    var bar = $(".ui-progressbar-value", obj);
    switch (true) {
      case (val <= 25):
        bar.css('background', 'LightGreen');
        break;
      case (val > 25 && val <= 50):
        bar.css('background', 'Yellow');
        break;
      case (val > 50 && val <= 75):
        bar.css('background', 'Orange');
        break;
      case (val > 75):
        bar.css('background', 'Red');
        break;
    }
  }

  function makeBar(obj) {
    obj.progressbar({
      value: 0,
      change: function(e, ui) {
        $(".label", this).text($(this).progressbar("value") + "% Complete!");
        checkValue($(this));
      }
    });
  }

  makeBar($("#progressbar"));
  makeBar($("#progressbar2"));

  function progress() {
    let val = progressbar.progressbar("value") || 0;
    let val2 = progressbar2.progressbar("value") || 0;
    if (val < 50) {
      progressbar.progressbar("value", val + 1);
    }
    if (val2 < 85) {
      progressbar2.progressbar("value", val2 + 1);
    }
    setTimeout(progress, 20);
  }
  setTimeout(progress, 500);
  // setTimeout(progress2, 500);
});
```

Hope that helps.